# Ansible playbook to run a command for each subdirectory in a directory

Tags: ansible

I have a following directory structure:

```
parent_dir/
├── subdir_1
├── subdir_2
└── subdir_3
```

The subdirs don't have a fixed name and there can be an arbitrary number of them.

How to make ansible run a task for each sub directory?

(any task will do, eventually every dir will be a python package to install, but that isn't important for the context of this question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I managed to come up with, perhaps there is a cleaner way with [lookups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html) to achieve this in a single task.

Copy pasting the following code will create a directory structure with a minimal ansible playbook that does the required. (tested on Ubuntu/dash)

```
mkdir action_per_dir
cd action_per_dir 
mkdir -p parent_dir/subdir_1 parent_dir/subdir_2 parent_dir/subdir_3

cat > action_per_dir.yml << "EOF"
---
# Gets all the directories and stores all the return values of `find`
# into the results_of_find
# The return value will consist of: 
# https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html#return-values
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Get all dirs
    find:
      paths: parent_dir
      file_type: directory
    register: result_of_find

# We're interested only in the `files` part of results of find.
# In pseudo code what's happening here is:
#     for each item in result_of_find.files:
#         print item.path
#
# The output will be very verbose but for debugging purposes it can be filtered
# ansible-playbook action_per_dir.yml | grep msg
  - name: Print all the dirs
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.path }}"
    with_items: "{{ result_of_find.files }}"
EOF
```

After that it just needs to be run:

```
ansible-playbook action_per_dir.yml | grep msg
```

Comment: This seems like a fine solution. I think using the `find` module to get the list of directories is probably the best way to do it.